# Wildcard in GNU makefile

Tags: makefile, markdown, gnu

I have many text files in a markdown text format and I want to use GNU make for generating HTML output. I have this Makefile that works with only one file:

```
MARKDOWN=markdown2

all: my_article_1242323266.html

%.html: %.markdown
    $(MARKDOWN) $< $@

clean:
    rm -f *html
```

Now, I want to get it working with all the markdown/html files, but I **do not want to list all my files in the Makefile**. I tried $(wildcard *.html) but it cannot not work as I dont have the "source" files in the directory yet. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MARKDOWN = markdown2
HTMLS = $(patsubst %.markdown,%.html,$(wildcard *.markdown))

all: $(HTMLS)

%.html: %.markdown
    $(MARKDOWN) $< $@

clean:
    rm -f $(HTMLS)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use something like this SOURCES=$(shell find . -name "*.cpp"  -print | sort). This will get all the cpp files

Comment: Well it does not work, it's listing html files but there are none.

Comment: There is no way it doesn't work if you have find and sort on your linux system which are installed by default i think. Do you change the extension to *.html?

Comment: Well the all target needs list of target and not sources. See my answer. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Thank v01d, I modified his solution into this:

```
MARKDOWN=markdown2

SOURCES=$(shell find . -name "*.markdown" | sed 's/markdown/html/')

all: $(SOURCES)

%.html: %.markdown
    $(MARKDOWN) $< $@

clean:
    rm -f *html
```

Comment: This solution has four drawbacks. First, it doesn't work for filenames such as markdown-tutorial.markdown. Second, it requires external commands "find" and "sed". These are most likely available under Linux/Unix, but a make-only solution will be faster. Third, variable name SOURCES is misleading because it contains targets. Last, "make clean" should delete only targets. See my answer.